# Accepting html safely in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

I need to accept html input (template) from user. I need to then compile it using angular's $interpolate function.
So when I get the html from user, I do this.

```
let $interpolate = this.$injector.get('$interpolate');
let $sanitize = this.$injector.get('$sanitize');
let html = $sanitize(toReturnStyles.cellTemplate);
 el = $interpolate(html)(params);
```

Then I checked adding  , I am good, alert didn't work.
But then I put following code in the inputbox and I saw alerts.

```
{{constructor.constructor('alert(1)')()}}
```

Please help me implement this usecase correctly.

Comment: Which version of AngularJS are you using? The sandbox was removed with V1.6. For more information, see [AngularJS Blog - Angular 1.6 - Expression Sandbox Removal](https://blog.angularjs.org/2016/09/angular-16-expression-sandbox-removal.html). [Also](https://portswigger.net/blog/xss-without-html-client-side-template-injection-with-angularjs).

Comment: I am using version 1.6.7